# how to use yii2-bootstrap4 extension with bootstrap 3 in the same app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, bootstrap-4, yii2-basic-app

I have tried to install [yii2-bootstrap4](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4)
but I got this composer error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4 ^1.0@dev -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4[1.0.x-dev].
- Conclusion: don't install bower-asset/bootstrap v3.3.7
- yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4 1.0.x-dev requires bower-asset/bootstrap ~4.0.0 -> satisfiable by bower-asset/bootstrap[v4.0.0, v4.0.0-beta.3, v4.0.0-beta1, v4.0.0-alpha.6, v4.0.0-alpha.5, v4.0.0-alpha.4, v4.0.0-alpha.3, v4.0.0-alpha.2, v4.0.0-alpha1].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0-beta.3].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0-beta1].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0-alpha.6].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0-alpha.5].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0-alpha.4].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0-alpha.3].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0-alpha.2].
- Can only install one of: bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7, v4.0.0-alpha1].
- Installation request for bower-asset/bootstrap (locked at v3.3.7) -> satisfiable by bower-asset/bootstrap[v3.3.7].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content
```

I want to be able to use bootstrap3 and 4 in the same app, I also tried what is described in this [issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4/issues/11) `"prefer-stable": true,` and did not work also.
so what exactly should I do, **how to use both bootstrap:~3.0 and bootstrap:~4.0 with official yii2-bootstrap packages**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of solution on how to use Bootstrap 4 in Yii2. Even the Yii2 team created an [extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4) for that. But since, I don't like too much configuration. This is what I did. In AppAsset.php, remove the yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset with custom your own. I'll recommend, you stick with the original filename and classname.

```
// AppAsset.php
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    //'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',  // Remove this
    'app\assets\BootstrapAsset',       // Add this
];
```

Then, I created a BootstrapAsset.php file in assets folder. Copy the code from yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset. Then changed some part of the code. No NPM, No Bower.

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class BootstrapAsset extends AssetBundle
{
  public $basePath = '@webroot';
  public $baseUrl = '@web';
  public $css = [
    'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  ];
  public $js = [
    'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js'
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to override some requirements in this way:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.8",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "1.0.x-dev",
    "bower-asset/bootstrap": "3.3.7 as 4.1.3",
    "npm-asset/bootstrap": "~4.1.3"
},
```

This will install bootstrap 3.3.7 from bower and bootstrap 4.1.3 from npm. You need to update path for bootstrap4 assets bundles:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => '@npm/bootstrap/dist'
            ],
            'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => '@npm/bootstrap/dist'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Note that [`yii2-bootstrap4`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4) is not ready to use and does not even have a alpha/beta release, so expect many other problems.